# How can you stop iOS Safari from jumping content under the address bar?

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm currently building a *really* simply HTML page. Essentially it contains a logo, 3 paragraphs of text (each contains about 1 sentence), and then a smaller paragraph as a footer at the bottom.

When I load this page on my iPhone, the page "jumps up" so as the top of the page is underneath the address bar. It's as if I've set `minimal-ui` and the address bar didn't disappear, but I haven't done that. I'm just using the standard tag,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I know `minimal-ui` more or less gets rid of the address bar and shows the top of the page at the top, but how can I do the reverse? I want the address bar to show, but I don't want my page going underneath it on initial render.

Apologies for not having any links, this isn't public anywhere yet.

Comment: It might be worth a shot to also add `height=device-height` to your VP metatag. Good luck!